# How do I obtain a mask, reversing numpy.flatnonzero?

Tags: python, numpy, ipython

Given an arbitrary one-dimensional mask:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
   ...: mask = np.array(np.random.random_integers(0,1,20), dtype=bool)
   ...: mask
Out[1]: 
array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

We can obtain an array of the `True` elements of `mask` using `np.flatnonzero`:

```
In[2]: np.flatnonzero(mask)
Out[2]: array([ 0,  2,  5,  7,  8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 19], dtype=int64)
```

But now how do I reverse this process and go from `_2` to a mask?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an all-false mask and then use numpy's [index array functionality](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays) to assign the `True` entries for the mask.

```
In[3]: new_mask = np.zeros(20, dtype=bool)
  ...: new_mask
Out[3]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False], dtype=bool)

In[4]: new_mask[_2] = True
  ...: new_mask
Out[4]: 
array([ True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True,  True,
       False,  True, False,  True, False, False,  True,  True, False,
        True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

As a check we see that:

```
In[5]: np.flatnonzero(new_mask)
Out[5]: array([ 0,  2,  5,  7,  8, 10, 12, 15, 16, 18, 19], dtype=int64)
```

As expected, `_5 == _2`:

```
In[6]: np.all(_5 == _2)
Out[6]: True
```

Comment: This feels like the (slightly) faster approach. Also a bit more intuitive.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `np.bincount`:

```
In [304]: mask = np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, size=10).astype(bool); mask
Out[304]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)

In [305]: idx = np.flatnonzero(mask); idx
Out[305]: array([0, 1, 3, 7, 9])

In [306]: np.bincount(idx, minlength=len(mask)).astype(bool)
Out[306]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```